# Gradient of $\sum_{i,j}^n A_{ij}x_i^TB^iC{B^j}^Tx_j$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

Suppose I have a symmetric matrix $A$ and $C$ and matrices $B_i$ of respective size. Then for vectors (of different dimension) $x_i$ I define the function

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}x_i^TB_iC{B_j}^Tx_j$$

and I would like to calculate the derivative or gradient of it. The reason I would like to find a solution of $\nabla f =0$.

Using the symmetry of $A$ I've ended up with

$$ \nabla f = 2\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \sum_{i=1}^nA_{1i}B_1C{B_i}^Tx_i \\
    \sum_{i=1}^nA_{2i}B_2C{B_i}^Tx_i \\
    \vdots \\
    \sum_{i=1}^nA_{ni}B_nC{B_i}^Tx_i 
    \end{array} \right]$$

is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure you want each index to appear thrice, not twice?

Comment: @J.G. yes indeed I want the index to appear thrice.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for your comment. So defining the block matrix $Q_{ij}:=A_{ij}B^iCB^j$ and $x$ as the stacked vector we can write $f$ as $x^TQx$. Hence $\nabla f = 2Qx$ so that the $j$-th component is given by $2\sum_{i=1}^n Q_{ji}x_i=2\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ji}B^jC{B^{i}}^Tx_i$. So guess my other derivation was correct?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I've changed the superscripts to subscripts. not sure about your second comment....do you say my answer is wrong or that one can just write it "nice". sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f \left( {\bf x}_1, \dots, {\bf x}_n \right) := \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} {\bf x}_i^\top {\bf B}_i {\bf C} \, {\bf B}_j^\top {\bf x}_j = \sum_{i,j=1}^n {\bf x}_i^\top \underbrace{\left( a_{ij} {\bf B}_i {\bf C} \, {\bf B}_j^\top \right)}_{=: {\bf Q}_{ij}} {\bf x}_j = {\bf x}^\top {\bf Q} \, {\bf x}$$

where

$$ {\bf Q} := \mbox{diag} \left( {\bf B}_1, \dots, {\bf B}_n \right) \left( {\bf A} \otimes {\bf C} \right) \mbox{diag} \left( {\bf B}_1, \dots, {\bf B}_n \right)^\top $$

where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. Note that $\bf Q$ is symmetric. Thus,

$$ \nabla_{{\bf x}} f \left( {\bf x} \right) = 2 \, {\bf Q} \, {\bf x} $$

Comment: Thanks for the comment.....But isn't $Q$ symmetric so that we end up with $2Q$ as thought?

Comment: @math I did not have the time to check carefully, but I think you are correct.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Are you using MATLAB?

Comment: Not really, why? could one get derivatives there? I've calculated it for a simple case by hand :)

Comment: I was wondering how you would solve $\bf{Q \, x} = 0$.